# How To Increase The Number of Parallel Running Map Tasks in MR or Hive CDH

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

MR job is launched with 128 mappers, but only 7 are running in parallel. How can I increase the number of parallel running map tasks?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`
This will set the maximum number of map tasks that can be run simultaneously at tasktracker level.

To set it at job level, you can use `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit`.

Comment: Parameters what you mentioned is to prevent going the max limit, I need something to increase the limit.